# How can I make Python code more efficient?

Tags: python

Newbie here.
I have this code, that displays all possible sums to reach a certain number.
But its complexity is too high and it takes too longe when numbers are too high. How can I refactor this to something more simple?

```
import itertools

def combos(n):

    result = []
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        for seq in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1,n+1), i):
            if sum(seq) == n:
                seq = list(seq)
                result.append(seq)
    return(result)

combos(4)
```

output:

```
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[4]]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Working code. Wanting to make it better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790/305121)-questions belong to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow.

Comment: Performance-based questions are fine here, but you need to be **very** specific. Is this an order of complexity issue or one where you want to implement the same logic faster? In either case, what are you aiming for? What timings do you currently see and on which Python version?

Comment: It's not actually the fault of your code, this problem is ugly due to the exploding number of solutions. The idea to keep these all in memory should be abandoned in favour of outputting each solution when it is foound. I would try a recursive approach, to avoid searching hopeless cases (one 4 in your example is sufficient to terminate everything).

Comment: @guidot could you explain your point a little better? I don't think i fully get it, but I think it is the way I should go

Answer (score 0):

The recursive version could be like this:

```
def combinations_max_sum(sum_max, i_max=None):

    if sum_max == 0:
        return [()]

    if not i_max or i_max > sum_max:
        i_max = sum_max

    combinations = [(i, *right_part)
                    for i in range(i_max, 0, -1)
                    for right_part in combinations_max_sum(sum_max-i, i_max=i)]

    return combinations
```

Test:

```
print(combinations_max_sum(4)) # [(4,), (3, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
print(combinations_max_sum(4, i_max=1)) # [(1, 1, 1, 1)]
print(combinations_max_sum(5))
# [(5,), (4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

The idea to decompose the problem: a set of combinations can be written as a number concatenated with all the combinations for which the sum is `n` minus that first number.

A simpler code without dealing with repetition could be like this:

```
def combinations_with_repetition(n):

    if n == 0:
        return [()]

    combinations = [(i, *right_part)  # concatenation
                    for i in range(1, n+1)  # for all possible first number 
                    for right_part in combinations_with_repetition(n-i)]
                    # ^ all possible combinations
                    #   given the first number i

    return combinations
```

which gives:

```
combinations_with_repetition(3)
# [(1, 2), (1, 1, 1), (2, 1), (3,)]
```

`(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` are similar, to prevent this a `i_max` argument is added (see the first function). The idea here is to go always in descending order. A number on the right is always equal or smaller than a number on the left. This maximum number is passed as an argument, and the loop start with it instead of the total sum asked.